# How do i relate an entity to an entity without saving a new version of the related entity

Tags: c#, entity-framework

I have 2 entities:

```
public class FileUploadType
{
    [Key]
    public int FileUploadTypeID { get; set; }

    public string Key { get; set; }
}

public class File
{
    [Key]
    public int FileID { get; set; }        

    public FileUploadType FileUploadType { get; set; }
    ...
}
```

When i try and attach a FileUploadType to a File in my controller and then run my repository Insert method, it creates a brand new FileUploadType:

```
File file = new File();

file.ItemID = Convert.ToInt32( itemID );
file.FileUploadType = this.fileUploadTypeRepository.GetByKey( uploadType );
this.fileRepository.Insert( file );
```

My repository looks like this:

```
public class EFFileRepository : EFGenericRepository<File>, IFileRepository
{
    ...
```

And my Generic is like this:

```
public class EFGenericRepository<T> where T : class
{
    internal protected EFDbContext context = new EFDbContext();
    internal protected DbSet<T> dbSet;
    ...

    public virtual T Insert( T entityToInsert )
    {
        ...

        dbSet.Add( entityToInsert );
        context.SaveChanges();

        return entityToInsert;
    }
```

My Db context looks like this:

```
public class EFDbContext : IdentityDbContext<ApplicationUser>
{
    public DbSet<File> Files { get; set; }
    public DbSet<FileUploadType> FileUploadTypes { get; set; }

    protected override void OnModelCreating( DbModelBuilder modelBuilder )
    {
        // base.OnModelCreating( modelBuilder );
        Precision.ConfigureModelBuilder(modelBuilder);

        modelBuilder.Entity<IdentityUserLogin>().HasKey<string>( l => l.UserId );
        modelBuilder.Entity<IdentityRole>().HasKey<string>( r => r.Id );
        modelBuilder.Entity<IdentityUserRole>().HasKey( r => new { r.RoleId, r.UserId } );
    }

    public static EFDbContext Create()
    {
        return new EFDbContext();
    }
}
```

Comment: What error do you get?

Comment: FileUploadType entity belongs to DbContext from FileUploadType repository, and File belongs to FileReposirotory. You need to attach FileUploadType entity to FileRepository. It'll be easier if you also use UnitOfWork.

Comment: Should I be using one EFDbContext throughout my application? rather than keep creating new ones inside each repository?

Comment: For winform, you should use one context per form or per view. For ASP.NET, you should use one context per request. See https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/data/jj729737.aspx

Comment: Oh my goodness.. What an arse that was. Had to change my whole set up! I now have a unit of work class that creates the new EFDbContext and passes that through to each EFRepository.. then in the construct of the EFRepository (which inherit from GenericRepository), I pass into : base( context ) so that everything is using that 1 EFDbContext per route. <sweats> and it's working. Thanks budovsky!